# Unable to start the Appdynamics server agent

Tags: appdynamics, app-dynamics-query-language

Agent does not start when switching to AppServerAgent-23.1.0. Formerly used
App Server Agent-22.2.0.

When starting the docker container, it says the following:

```
File java9-impl.jar does not exist. Please check java agent package.
Java 9+ detected, booting with Java9Util enabled.
Java agent fails to initialize under Java 9 because: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/singularity/ee/agent/appagent/java9/Java9Util
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/singularity/ee/agent/appagent/java9/Java9Util
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
        at com.singularity.ee.agent.appagent.AgentEntryPoint.premain(AgentEntryPoint.java:512)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:491)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:503)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/singularity/ee/agent/appagent/java9/Java9Util
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
        at com.singularity.ee.agent.appagent.AgentEntryPoint.premain(AgentEntryPoint.java:512)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:491)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:503)
```

Settings have not changed. Using java 17 (liberica)

Answer (score 0):

To resolve, kindly verify:

1. Is the file "java9-impl.jar" present in the agent directory? (<agent-directory>/multi-release/java9-impl.jar) - if not then redeploy ensuring the full zip is extacted / placed
2. If the .jar is present then this is likely a permissions issue. Ensure that the user being used to run the application / JVM has access to all contents of the agent directory